# Apply fxaa to scene but except some textures

Tags: three.js, texturing, fxaa

I have some scene in three.js with static objects like solid cubes and so on.

Over this objects I have place some quads each of them is textured with letter image.

When I activate fxaa postprocessing main objects looks fine but letters textures looks not good - blurry and dirty. I think it's because letter texture already antialiased. I can't generate another type of textures because Chrome render font already antialiased and I just get screenshot for texture.

Is it possible somehow exclude some objects from fxaa pass? Maybe make more render passes? Any ideas or samples?

Thanks.

Comment: Nobody helps me? @WestLangley maybe you have solution as three.js team member?